# Símbolos extraños en datos de una tabla MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Dispongo de una base de datos en MySQL, ya dada, con diferentes tablas.

Algunas de columnas con claves primarias (las cuales me permite editar manualmente) y otras sin clave primaria (no me permite editar manualmente).

El **motivo** se debe al siguiente mensaje:

> La selección actual no contiene una columna única. La edición de la grilla y los enlaces de copiado, eliminación y edición no están disponibles.

Mi intención es **solucionar el tema de las "ñ", tildes y acentos** debido a que no los reconoce en la base de datos. ¿Tendría que ir modificar cada dato mediante un `UPDATE` o se puede resolver de una vez?

Ejemplo de cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución que veo es actualizar el dato de cada fila y de cada tabla:

```
UPDATE tabla SET titulo="Consultorio médico" WHERE id_publicacion=164;
```

Tras realizar el UPDATE en id_publicacion=164:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así sucesivamente... **¿Es cuestión del acotejamiento? ¿Se puede resolver todo de una vez?**

He probado las siguientes sentencias sin suerte:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Lo mejor para cualquier programa, aplicación, base de datos y básicamente **todo**, es _no_ ocupar acentos como tilde, "ñ" o cualquier otro carácter que no esté en el alfabeto inglés; con tu pregunta... Hasta donde conozco, la única forma de solucionar eso es que vayas 1 a 1, actualizando los datos, es horrible hacer eso, pero creo es la única forma, lo lamento si me equivoco.

Comment: Al menos en los datos que muestras se ve que por algún descuido (el cual deberías revisar si sigues insertando desde esa fuente), los datos se insertaron codificados como [entidades html](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Entidades_de_caracteres_XML_y_HTML). Si están todos así no será tan complicado. Puedes hacer una función en PHP que lea automáticamente las columnas implicadas, las decodifique y las actualice decodificadas. Ver por ejemplo para PHP [esta función](http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php). Creo que MySQL  no tiene una función propia, las hay de terceros...

Comment: ... si no existe función nativa de MySQl yo lo haría con algún programa, PHP u otro. Eso sí, ante nada, haz una copia de la BD en cada etapa de reemplazo.

Comment: aqui muestran como crear una funcion en Mysql para decodificar las entidades html o como se dice en ingles html entities. si la modificas un poco puedes usar para actualizar el campo.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es espeficicarle a la base de datos que acepte todos los caracteres, y no tener inconvenientes en un futuro por lo mismo.

Al crear la base de datos debes hacerlo con la siguiente estructura:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

si es una base de datos ya creada, puedes modificarla con un alter:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: He realizado tu comando y no me ha realizado ningún cambio. También probé la siguiente sentencia sin suerte: ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: Pero has probado añadiendo nuevas cosas a ver cómo se guardan ahora?

Comment: @Alejandro Lo que quiero no es añadir nuevos registros, sino modificar los registros ya existentes de las tablas.

Comment: Es que lo ya insertado no se modifica al cambiar el CHARSET ni el COLLATE, para ello deberás actualizar los registros.

Comment: Quizas sea de su interés el siguiente contenido: https://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8 , pues es un convert

Comment: @Millán Gracias por el link adjuntado pero de poca ayuda me ha servido. Sigo teniendo el mismo problema, me siguen saliendo los caracteres extraños.

Comment: Listo, veo que los caracteres con los cuales tienes inconveniente tienen en común las tildes, estas tildes son las comunes de HTML, &_acute; Lo que debes hacer es un replace con un REGEXP, donde cambie el primer caractér luego de la & por la bocal tildada. Por ejemplo: &eacute; -> é . Prueba haciendo un update a un registro, una vez la tenga funcional puedes repetirlo donde lo requiera, puede ser con un procedimiento almacenado.