# Problemas para representar tildes y ñ en página web con datos extraídos de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

tengo algunos problemas para mostrar tildes y la letra ñ en una página web donde estoy haciendo `echo` a datos que estoy seleccionando de la base de datos, en vez de aparecer las tildes y la ñ sale �, estoy utilizando phpmyadmin con wampserver 3.2.3 de 32 bits. Me he asegurado de que las tablas tengan la collation de `utf8_unicode_ci` y que las columnas dentro de las tablas tengan la collation `utf8_unicode_ci`, incluso las he cambiado a `utf8_unicode_spanish` y todavía siguen sin aparecer las ñ y tildes, incluso en el `head` de html me asegure de que sea asi: `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Aqui les adjuntare imagenes de la interfaz de base de datos para que puedan comprobar que todas las collations están como comenté.

[image: la tabla de cursos con la collation]

[image: todas las tablas con la collation que corresponden]

Si necesitan que también muestre el código, tambien lo mostrare.

```
<?php include_once("includes/encabezado.php"); ?>

<?php include_once("includes/navegacion.php"); ?>

    <div class="contenedor contenedor-header">
        <main>
        <h1 class="titulo-lista-cursos">Nuestros cursos</h1>    
        
        
        <?php

    
        
        //comandos SQL para seleccionar datos de tablas curso y modalidad_curso

        $query = "SELECT nombre_curso, descripcion_curso, dificultad_curso, area_curso, fecha_curso, img_curso, modalidad_curso.modalidad FROM curso "; 
        $query .= "INNER JOIN modalidad_curso ON curso.id_modalidad = modalidad_curso.id_modalidad ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY id_curso ASC";

        

        //crea consulta para mostrar cursos
        $seleccionar_cursos_query = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

        //termina la conexion en caso de que haya un fallo
        if(!$seleccionar_cursos_query) {
            die('Query fallido' . mysqli_error($conexion));
        } 

        //bucle while que extrae y coloca los datos de la base de datos en un array para mostrarlos en la pagina
        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seleccionar_cursos_query)) {

            $nombre_curso = $fila['nombre_curso'];
            $descripcion_curso = $fila['descripcion_curso'];
            $dificultad_curso = $fila['dificultad_curso'];
            $area_curso = $fila['area_curso'];
            $fecha_curso = $fila['fecha_curso'];
            $img_curso = $fila['img_curso'];
            $modalidad_curso = $fila['modalidad'];

        ?>

            <!-- infomaciong general de los cursos -->
            <div class="contenedor-lista-cursos">
            <article class="curso-info curso-info-childs">
            <h2><strong><?php echo $nombre_curso; ?></strong></h2>
            <img class="curso-lista-imagen" src="<?php echo $img_curso; ?>">

            <div class="direccion-fila">
            <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
            <small><?php echo $fecha_curso; ?></small>
            </div>

            <p>dificultad: <?php echo $dificultad_curso; ?></p>
            <p>area: <?php echo $area_curso; ?></p>
            <p>modalidad: <?php echo $modalidad_curso; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $descripcion_curso; ?></p>        
            <h3><a href="#">Leer más</a></h3>
            </article>

    <?php } ?>

        </div>
        </main>
    
        <?php include_once("includes/barra_lateral.php"); ?>

    </div>  

<?php include_once("includes/pie.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Y cómo se están guardando los datos? Es posible que se hayan guardado de forma incorrecta antes de los cambios. Lo otro, ese meta no afecta lo que haga PHP al interpretar tu script, deberías usar `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Símbolos extraños en datos de una tabla MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138591/s%c3%admbolos-extra%c3%b1os-en-datos-de-una-tabla-mysql)

Comment: @Alfabravo se están guardando como ´datatype TEXT´, y con respecto al meta, entonces debo agregar ´header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');´ en el mismo archivo php?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso gracias por compartir, pero en la misma base de datos si aparecen los acentos y ñ, es en la página que no aparecen correctamente

Comment: has intentado hacer lo que te dije en la respuesta???

Comment: si, ya se ha resuelto, muchisimas gracias, debía agregar el charset en la conexión,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

debes asegurarte de usar:

1. `utf8mb4_general_ci` para las Bases de Datos.
2. `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` en las tablas.
3. y que los datos que ya existan no estén corruptos.

Asegúrate de que tu conexión a la base de datos use `UTF-8` en el `set names`.
este ejemplo Implementa Driver PDO:

```php
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("set names utf8");
```

Documentacion parea mysqli: [Link-1](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php)

y que tus archivos (html,php,js) tengan un encode `UTF-8 sin BOM`
y que tu archivos output HTML en el `head` tenga el tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero yo estoy usando mysqli en el caso de la conexion de base de datos

Comment: puedes implementarlo tambien ... eso no es una limitante... [Link-1](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php)